# removing controls added during run time

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that has a text box and whatever value is put into the textbox will determine the number of dynamic controls that are added to the user form and then there is a button and once that is clicked I want the dynamic controls to be removed from the userform altogether.

Below shows the code that is used to create the dynamic controls and this code works perfectly

```
 For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
        newPosition = 360

        Set cLabel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
            With cLabel
                .Caption = "Label " & (i)
                .Font.Size = 8
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
                '.Left = 70
                .Left = 36
                .Top = switchBoardLevel
                .Width = 130
            End With


        switchBoardLevel = switchBoardLevel + newPosition           


        Set cButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With cButton
            .Name = "CommandButton" & i
            .Caption = "Calculate"
            .Left = 300
            .Top = buttonStartPosition
            .Width = 45
            .Height = 18
        End With

        ReDim Preserve TextListBox(1 To i)
        Set TextListBox(i).ButtonGroup = cButton

        buttonStartPosition = buttonStartPosition + newPosition
  Next i
```

However there is a problem when it comes to removing the dynamically created controls. I have tried numerous ways to remove the controls. The code below is executed when the button is clicked to remove the controls but it just won't work for me and I am going round in circles so It would be greatly appreciated if someone could give me some guidance on the issue.

```
For Each TextListBox(i).ButtonGroup In Me.Controls
   If (TypeOf TextListBox(i).ButtonGroup Is CommandButton) Then
      TextListBox(i).ButtonGroup.Visible = False
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given a lot of information but you can't loop that way - you need to loop through the array:

```
For i = Lbound(TextListBox) to UBound(TextListBox)
   If TypeOf TextListBox(i).ButtonGroup Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
      TextListBox(i).ButtonGroup.Visible = False
   End If
Next
```

Comment: sorry i'm only getting the chance to get back to you on this post but that fix didn't work because `UBound` is coming up as -1 for some reason!

Comment: It seems your array has been lost then. Where is it declared?